# Cannont Add-Member as the Member with the Name Exists

Tags: arrays, powershell

Can someone help me out with getting the disk info? I have 3 disks but I'm unable to get their information using add member.

I get an error:

```
"Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "Disks" because a member with that name already exists. If you want to overwrite the member anyway, use the Force parameter to overwrite it."
```

This is my code:

```
function  Get-Inven {

param([string[]]$computername)

#Import-Module ActiveDirectory

foreach ($computer in $computername) {
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer -Filter 'DriveType=3'
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer
    #$comp = Get-ADComputer -Filter { cn=$computer }

    $info = @{
        'ComputerName'=$computer;
        'OSVersion'=$os.caption;
        'DnsHostName'=$comp.dnshostname
    }

    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $info

    foreach ($disk in $disks) {
        $info = @{
            'DriveLetter'=$disk.deviceID;
            'FreeSpace'=($disk.freespace / 1MB -as [int])
        }
        $diskobj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Info
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Disks -Value $diskobj
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still set the Name property if you add the -Force parameter. You should also add the -PassThru switch parameter to emit the object back to the pipeline:

```
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Disks -Value $diskobj -Force -PassThru
```

UPDATE:

In my opinion you can simplify the function (no add-member calls):

```
foreach ($computer in $computername) {
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer -Filter 'DriveType=3'
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer
    #$comp = Get-ADComputer -Filter { cn=$computer }

    $info = @{
        ComputerName=$computer
        OSVersion=$os.caption
        DnsHostName=$comp.dnshostname
        FreeSpaceMB= ($disks | foreach { "{0},{1:N0}" -f $_.Caption,($_.freespace/1MB) }) -join ';'
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $info 
}
```

Comment: The `-Force` parameter causes the value of the Disks property to be overwritten, and even though the `-PassThru` parameter emits an object each time, `Add-Member` is still referencing the same object. When you run this for a computer with multiple drives, you will get multiple objects with the same info for a single drive. On my machine with drives C:,D: and E:, I get 3 objects each with info for drive E:.

Comment: I was commenting about the -Force because you got an error ans I wanted to show you that you can override the Name property. Anyway, I've updated the thread, adding my 2c on the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are multiple disks, you need to create the disk property as an array, then add each disk to the array. Also, remember to output `$obj` at the end of the `$computername` foreach.

```
function  Get-Inven {

param([string[]]$computername)
$computername = 'localhost'
foreach ($computer in $computername) {
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer -Filter 'DriveType=3'
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer
    #$comp = Get-ADComputer -Filter { cn=$computer }

    $info = @{
        'ComputerName'=$computer;
        'OSVersion'=$os.caption;
        'DnsHostName'=$comp.dnshostname
    }

    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $info 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Disks -Value @()
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name DisksList -Value {
        ($this.Disks|%{$_.DriveLetter + ',' + $_.FreeSpace}) -join ';'
    }
    foreach ($disk in $disks) {
        $info = @{
            'DriveLetter'=$disk.deviceID;
            'FreeSpace'=($disk.freespace / 1MB -as [int])
        }
        $diskobj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Info
        $obj.Disks += $diskobj
    }
    $obj
}
}

$result = get-inven localhost
$result| select "OSVersion","DnsHostName","ComputerName","DisksList"|ConvertTo-Csv
```

Comment: Hi @Rynant, Thanks for the help, i had one more question when i output the result of tis function to a csv i get the disks as System.Object[] type, & i see they are not filled with teh original values, can you pelase help me.

Comment: You could either create a complete object for each disk by placing the `New-Object` inside the $disks foreach, and not creating the disk property as an array. Alternatively, you could create a ScriptProperty member to display the disks the way you want them displayed. I'll update my answer with an example.